# Can we install .Net framework 4.0 in Windows server 2016?

Tags: windows-server-2016, .net-4.0

By default windows server 2016 giving framework 4.7. Our application is in framework 4.0 and may be because of that we are getting weird issues so I need to install framework 4.0 on windows server 2016.

I have tried but I could not as its giving error that this is already installed as its part of OS.

Let me know if there is any way to do that.

Comment: No, you cannot install an older version of .NET Framework 4.0 on Windows Server 2016. Even if you could, you should not, due to the oldest supported version of .NET Framework 4 for any platform is 4.5.2.

Comment: You probably should update your application, instead.

Comment: Please refer to the following topic: https://superuser.com/a/1183727/240625